# Un mot pour quelqu'un qui économise mais qui est généreux si nécessaire

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je cherche un mot pour désigner quelqu'un d'économe, mais qui a la noblesse de reconnaitre les situations dans lesquelles il faut être généreux, ce qui le distingue d'un mesquin. Un simple économe peut être mesquin, d'où ma question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Parcimonieux*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parcimonieux) sous-entend à mon avis le côté "généreux si nécessaire". Une personne parcimonieuse se distinguera d'une personne avare dans ce sens qu'elle ne dépensera pas son argent à tout va, mais saura le mettre à disposition en cas de besoin, possiblement en grande quantité.

D'un autre côté, et bien que tu penses le contraire, je trouve que *économe* correspond plutôt bien au sens que tu recherches. Bien évidemment qu'il n'exclut pas totalement le côté *mesquin*, mais il ne le sous-entend pas non plus, loin de là.

Comment: *innécessairement* fleure bon l'anglicisme inconnu, même chez Wikipédia

Comment: @cl-r : bien vu!

Answer (score 1):

Les synonymes *d'économe* sont tournés vers la réduction de dépense : *parcimonieux, regardant, rapiat, chiche* ; jusqu'à l'excès : *radin, avare*.

Il n'y à pas dans *économe* de synonyme ouvrant la porte à *généreux* et vice-versa.

Ce n'est pas un mot qui vient à l'esprit pour répondre à la question, mais une définition d'aptitude sociale:

> Dépenser son argent à bon escient et être capable de libéralités.

*Libéralité* : Disposition à donner généreusement ; synonyme par ordre d'importance : charité, générosité, largesse, magnificence, munificence ; excès : *prodigalité, profusion*.
Pour ce qui concerne les objets, les synonymes sont : *aumône, bienfait, cadeau, gratification, largesse*.

---

Références extraites du Robert